# Retrieving maps from a sequence based on contents - Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a data set in the format

```
{:application "name1", :date "date1", :description "desc1"}
{:application "name1", :date "date2", :description "desc2"}
{:application "name2", :date "date1", :description "desc1"}
{:application "name2", :date "date2", :description "desc2"}
etc ...)
```

My goal is to create a sequence containing the maps for an individual application, as below.

```
{:application "name1", :date "date1", :description "desc1"}
{:application "name1", :date "date2", :description "desc2"}
```

I've tried a number of different ways to do this but can't seem to get any to work. My current thinking for how to do it is:

```
(let[
 a (for [x data] (if (= (get x :application) "name1") x))
])
```

I know there is probably a simple solution to this, but I'm new to Clojure and I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

David

Comment: I find myself thinking in looping constructs a lot too, you might consider doing the problem sets at 4clojure.com to help you get rid of it.  It's definitely helping me.  I now start thinking with map, comp etc instead of (ok i have to build a list, then i transform the list etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you only want name1

`(filter (comp #{"name1"} :application) data)`

to sort by name

`(group-by :application data)`

Comment: Nice answer. @David - just to expand on something a bit subtle here - `#{"name1"}` is a set and `:application` is a keyword. In this answer, both are actually acting as functions. A keyword, when called with a map as an argument, returns the associated value (or nil otherwise). A set, when called with a value as an argument, returns the value if it is in the set, or nil otherwise. When composed together (using `comp`), the result is a function that will look up the `:association` key and return "name1" if it is "name1" or nil otherwise.

Comment: If your data set is a set use clojure.set/select in the same manner as filter in the first snippet.